# React Google Maps is not rendering markers consistently

Tags: google-maps, react-google-maps

I have the following code to render multiple markers on a React Google Maps map and the markers do not always render.  If I comment out the info for bar 1 and bar 2, save, and uncomment that information the markers will render 80% of the time.  If I hard code the current location only, the marker will always render.  I have no idea what I’m doing wrong here, most likely an ID-10-T error on my part.  Thanks in advance for any help on this matter.

```
/* global google */

import React from "react"
import { compose, withProps, withStateHandlers } from "recompose"
import {
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
    GoogleMap,
    Marker,
    InfoWindow,
} from "react-google-maps"

const MyMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[api key goes here]&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `600px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `75vh`, width: '50vw' }} />,
    }),
    withStateHandlers(() => ({
        isOpen: false,
    }), {
            onToggleOpen: ({ isOpen }) => () => ({
                isOpen: !isOpen,
            })
        }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)((props) =>
    <GoogleMap
        zoom={15}
        center={props.currentLocation}
    >
        {props.markerList.map((marker, index) => {
            return (
                <Marker
                    position={{
                        lat: marker.lat,
                        lng: marker.lng
                    }}
                    onClick={props.onToggleOpen}
                    title={marker.name}
                    key={marker.name}
                >
                    {props.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Info Window</h3>
                            <h4>Testing</h4>
                        </div>
                    </InfoWindow>}
                </Marker>
            )
        })};

    </GoogleMap>
);

const markers = [
    {
        lat: 38.3332416,
        lng: -95.63961839999999,
        name: "bar 1"
    },
    {
        lat: 38.0332416,
        lng: -95.63971639999999,
        name: "bar 2"
    }
];

class MyFancyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {
        isMarkerShown: false,
    }


    componentWillMount() {
        this.getGeoLocation()
    }

    getGeoLocation = () => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                position => {
                    this.setState({
                        currentLatLng: {
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lng: position.coords.longitude,
                            name: "current location"
                        }
                    })
                    markers.unshift(this.state.currentLatLng);
                }
            )
        } else {
            error => console.log(error)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyMapComponent
                currentLocation={this.state.currentLatLng}
                markerList={markers}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default MyFancyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is when the position is determined ( callback function of `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is executed) `MyMapComponent` component might already get rendered, that's most likely the reason why markers are rendered inconsistently.

To eliminate this behavior the following solution could be considered.

Since `MyFancyComponent` is already a stateful  component i would suggest to introduce `markers` state and set the initial values like this:

```
class MyFancyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    isMarkerShown: false,
    markers: markers
  };

  //...
}
```

Then, once the current location is determined, state could be updated like this:

```
getGeoLocation = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {

        let latLng = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
            name: "current location"
          };

        this.setState( prevState => ({
          currentLatLng: latLng,
          markers: [latLng,...prevState.markers]
        }));
      });
    } else {
      error => console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

and finally passed down into `MyMapComponent` component as props:

```
<MyMapComponent
        currentLocation={this.state.currentLatLng}
        markerList={this.state.markers}
      />
```